# How to draw a segmented barplot with different sub-categories in each bar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, categories

```py
COUNT = {"Objects":500,
         "Female":100, "Male":100,
         "Apples":50, "Oranges":20, "Grapes":40
        }
```

Suppose I have counting data of several specific categories. I want to draw a **barplot** to illustrate the higher-level catogorization, say, counts of "Objects", "Human", and "Fruit", and then describe the specific catogories with segmentations of the 2nd and the 3rd bar. Basically, I need to generate a **segmented barplot with different sub-categories** in each bar. How can I do that with Python?

Comment: Does what you've done match [this page:Grouped bar chart with labels](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-barchart-py)

Comment: @r-beginners Thank you! It's similar but every group has different subgroups. Like HUMAN has "female" and "male", and FRUIT has "apples", "oranges", and "grapes".

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I decide to use pie chart